# Does Rooting Exploit a Security Weakness?

Tags: rooting

According to the [Wikipedia page for Android rooting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_rooting),

> The process of rooting varies widely by device, **but usually includes exploiting a security weakness in the firmware of the device**, and then copying the `su` binary to a location in the current process's PATH (e.g. `/system/xbin/su`) and granting it executable permissions with the `chmod` command. A supervisor application like SuperUser or SuperSU can regulate and log elevated permission requests from other applications. Many guides, tutorials, and automatic processes exist for popular Android devices facilitating a fast and easy rooting process.

Now, I wanted to know what exploits are being used in this process so I started looking around.  I did find a couple references to Android exploits (notably [RageAgainstTheCode](https://thesnkchrmr.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/rageagainstthecage/)), but a couple questions on here ([this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22884/how-does-rooting-work) and [How does su regulate app permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6957/how-does-su-regulate-app-permissions/)) give me the impression that no actual exploit is being performed.

From what I have gathered the process works like such:

1. Unlock bootloader ([wipes device for security concerns](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33691/why-does-unlocking-the-booloader-wipe-phone))
2. Install custom recovery (will allow flashing arbitrary ZIP files)
3. Flash SuperUser or SuperSU zip file in custom recovery.

As I understand it, the custom recovery is able to flash the ZIP file because it exists at a lower level (so to speak) than the ROM, and as such, can modify the ROM to install the `su` binary and SuperUser app.  That is, no real exploit is being used to attain root.

Am I grossly missing something here? Is some exploit being performed implicitly during one of these steps?

As a note, I'm talking about a user rooting a phone, not about a malicious piece of code getting root access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, there's nothing like *THE* rooting process. You partly answered your question yourself: rooting a device can be done in different ways. The two best known methods include:

- using an exploit (SuperOneClick & Co do this: You install an app, klick it, and get rooted)
- via a custom recovery (which is directly bootable and thus can access the device directly, so you can install any ROM -- which in turn may already be rooted)

So answering your question: Yes and no -- it all depends on *how* you root your device. Listing up all possible exploits might get a bit lengthy, so better let's skip that part. You might also check the questions in the "related" section of this page for more details (especially [What are the steps for rooting an Android device, in general?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16466/)).